# Problem connecting to Oracle database via ASP.NET page under IIS

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I'm having a problem getting a simple ASP.NET webpage to display. The page contains a GridView with a SqlDataSource connected to an Oracle database.

When I run the page in the VS debugger (cassini webserver) everything works fine, but when I publish the application to my local IIS server (same machine), I get the following error:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

If it was a different machine I could understand that it might be a tnsnames.ora or other problem that I could investigate via tnsping. I have also set the security on the folder containing the Oracle drivers to "Everybody", and set the webapp to run under a "Priviliged" AppPool (Identity as Administrator), but with no success.

Anyone else got any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255084) guide is a bible for this kinds of problems :)

Actually i have printed one copy of this guide and distribute it to every consultant involved with IIS ASP.NET to ORACLE connectivity issues. The checklist will probably get your problem solved, unless you have a problem within your code which you don't seem to have based on your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, this led me to the solution - I had got a custom install of the Oracle client (which worked fine for everything else). When I replaced it with the standard client install everything worked...

Answer (score 0):

I think you more than 1 Oracle client. You need to search **ALL** your tnsnames.ora files with the windows explorer and compare and synchronize **ALL** those files.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you need to specify the IP

Comment: no ip is needed, connection is done through Oracle Client of the same machine.